# Cannot start up logstash because of config error

Tags: logging, logstash, settings

So i'm in the middle of setting up ELK i succeed installing elastic and kibana but got an error in starting logsearch, this is the error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/C:/Users/10992005/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby-8888/jruby13233270349330806025jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to D:/new_logging/logstash-7.9.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-03-17T14:33:41,160][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.9.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10-LTS on 11.0.8+10-LTS +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-03-17T14:33:41,441][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-03-17T14:33:42,349][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\" at line 13, column 16 (byte 244) after output {\n\tstdou
t{ codec => rubydebug }\n\telasticsearch ", :backtrace=>["D:/new_logging/logstash-7.9.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:183:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "D:
/new_logging/logstash-7.9.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:44:in `initialize'", "D:/new_logging/logstash-7.9.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "D:/new_logging/logstash-7.9.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:357:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2021-03-17T14:33:42,685][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-03-17T14:33:47,766][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-03-17T14:33:47,779][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

as far as i know this is logstash config problem but i didnt know where's the error(although the error did tell me its in line 13 but i didnt know whats wrong), i'm new to ELK please tell me how to fix it
here's the logstash config

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
    file{
        type => "syslog"
        path => "D:/new_logging/log/application.log"
    }
}

output {
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch => {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "testing"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is exactly at line 13: `elasticsearch => {` , please drop the `=>` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html)

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
    file{
        type => "syslog"
        path => "D:/new_logging/log/application.log"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "testing"
    }
}
```

Comment: Damnit i didnt see that thank you this solve my problem